# BottomSheetDialog disable dragging

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog, android-alertdialog, bottom-sheet

I have `Bottomsheetdialog` with Custom view having `EditText` and on `EditText` scrolling bottom sheet goes down, How to disable `BottomSheetDialog` dragging. Any Help Appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45513525/5603642

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but this works fine for me:

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);

    // This should do the job
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, It solved two problem I had.

1- It block the dragging event.

2- It solves the listView scrolling problem

```
CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> behavior;

    View profile_config_layout_bottom_sheet = findViewById(R.id.list_view_audience_profile_config_layout);
    
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) profile_config_layout_bottom_sheet.getLayoutParams();
        behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
        assert behavior != null;
        ((BottomSheetBehavior<View>) behavior).addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    ((BottomSheetBehavior<View>) behavior).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                } 
            }
            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {}
        });
```

Show the dialog with:

```
((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.