# Modal BottomSheetDialog with fullscreen ToolBar and Softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

How is it possible to create a modal `BottomSheetDialog(Fragment)` which switches to fullscreen with a ToolBar as shown in the [Material Design Spec](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#behavior)?

[image]

I *could* add a ToolBar manually by adding a `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback` and setting the alpha of the ToolBar depending on the slideOffset. This is a bit hacky but seems to work when moving the Bottom Sheet. However, this doesn't work when my Bottom Sheet contains an `EditText` and the Keyboard is shown. I tried both Versions: `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and manually adding the Behavior to a new Fragment.

- Is there an easier way to achieve this?
- Can I trigger the ToolBar when the Keyboard is shown and the Bottom Sheet uses up the whole space?

Comment: Have u check this  https://riptutorial.com/android/example/4458/bottomsheetbehavior-like-google-maps and https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior

Comment: Also you need to share your code

Comment: @dipdipdip What if you make your **Main layout container** of `BottomSheet` foucsable. In such a way, your `EditText` won't gain focus initially !

Comment: Initial focus is not a problem. Opening the keyboard in general is a problem. The ToolBar should also get visible (with an animation!) when the Content hits the top of the screen, no matter how it reaches it (scrolling the content, Bottom sheet Expand, Keyboard shown). I didn't get it work with this CustomBottomSheet and the Keyboard either.

Comment: @dipdipdip I am having trouble understanding if you need a complete solution for the material design feature or solve a specific bug in something you have already created; if it is the latter you should really give us some code (as Nilesh Rathod suggested) or at least a screen capture of the bug

Comment: No I need a solution how to implement this kind of Bottom sheet.

Comment: It reminds me of this gif, which may be similar: https://twitter.com/sbkurs/status/1044847256233541633

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218778/android-multi-line-text-edittext-inside-bottomsheetdialog

Comment: @AdamMc331 I didn't think about the new MotionLayout. Maybe I'll give it a try. But I don't want to lose the normal `BottomSheetBehavior`. I hope this works together.

Comment: @dipdipdip yeah, I'm only drawing similarities between what you showed and that gif, but I'm not confident it's the solution. That's why I went with comment and not answer for now haha

Comment: hi @dipdipdip Have you find a solution ? I have the same problem when keyboard is opened it's expanded below the status bar.

Comment: Sadly no. I also have this Keyboard issue.

Comment: OK thanks any way.

Answer (score -2):

I face the same issue.
This is what I solved.
The Behavior is hidden in BottomSheetDialog, which is available to get the behavior
If you would like not to change your parent layout to be CooridateLayout,
you can try this.

**STEP 1: customize the BottomSheetDialogFragment**

```
open class CBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
   //wanna get the bottomSheetDialog
   protected lateinit var dialog : BottomSheetDialog 
   override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
      dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
      return dialog
   }

   //set the behavior here
   fun setFullScreen(){
      dialog.behavior.state = STATE_EXPANDED
   }
}
```

**STEP 2: make your fragment extend this customized fragment**

```
class YourBottomSheetFragment : CBottomSheetDialogFragment(){

   //make sure invoke this method after view is built
   //such as after OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
   override fun onStart() {
      super.onStart()
      setFullScreen()//initiated at onActivityCreated(), onStart()
   }
}
```